# Can't get JSON data properly

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to get crypto data from this service https://coinmarketcap.com/api/ and Postman returns the following response body:

```
"status": {
    "timestamp": "2020-09-03T11:33:00.616Z",
    "error_code": 0,
    "error_message": null,
    "elapsed": 101,
    "credit_count": 1,
    "notice": null
},
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "slug": "bitcoin",
        "num_market_pairs": 8938,
        "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "tags": [
            "mineable",
            "pow",
            "sha-256",
            "store-of-value",
            "state-channels"
        ],
        "max_supply": 21000000,
        "circulating_supply": 18478475,
        "total_supply": 18478475,
        "platform": null,
        "cmc_rank": 1,
        "last_updated": "2020-09-03T11:31:33.000Z",
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 11273.4407683,
                "volume_24h": 25364037841.8901,
                "percent_change_1h": -0.600125,
                "percent_change_24h": -2.18778,
                "percent_change_7d": -0.96201,
                "market_cap": 208315993401.01236,
                "last_updated": "2020-09-03T11:31:33.000Z"
            }
        }
    },
```

Here's my JSON struct. I get the following errors. What can be wrong?

*valueNotFound(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil),
CodingKeys(stringValue: "quote", intValue: nil)*

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    var data: [CryptoData] 
}

struct CryptoData: Decodable {

var id: Int
var name: String
var symbol: String
var slug: String
var maxSupply: Int?
var totalSupply: QuantumValue
var rank: Int
var lastUpdated: String

var quote: QuoteDetails

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    
    case id
    case name
    case symbol
    case slug
    case maxSupply = "max_supply"
    case totalSupply = "total_supply"
    case rank = "cmc_rank"
    case lastUpdated = "last_updated"
    case quote
}
}

struct QuoteDetails: Decodable {
     var USD: QuoteUSD
}

struct QuoteUSD: Decodable {

var price: Double
var dailyVolume: Double
var percentChangeIn1h: Double
var percentChangeIn24h: Double
var percentChangeIn7d: Double
var marketCap: Double
var lastUpdated: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case price
    case dailyVolume = "volume_24h"
    case percentChangeIn1h = "percent_change_1h"
    case percentChangeIn24h = "percent_change_24h"
    case percentChangeIn7d = "percent_change_7d"
    case marketCap = "market_cap"
    case lastUpdated = "last_updated"
}
}
```

My function to make request:

```
func loadData() {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest") else {
        
        print("Wrong URL.")
        return
    }
    
    let finalURL = url
    var request = URLRequest(url: finalURL)
    request.addValue("c972ac08-519e-47e5-8cd8-23e6230289f3", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY")
    
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, responce, error) in
        
        if let jsonData = data {
            
            do {
                
                let cryptoData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
                print(cryptoData)
            }
            
            catch {
                
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've already fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the url/api key (which you should remove from the question), I found two issues with your data model.

First... the full error that is generated while parsing is:

```swift
valueNotFound(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 63", intValue: 63), CodingKeys(stringValue: "quote", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "USD", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "percent_change_7d", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected Double value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

One of the `QuoteUSD` has a NULL for a value. In order to parse this your `percentChangeIn7d` should become optional: `var percentChangeIn7d: Double?`.

Second...

```swift
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 90", intValue: 90), CodingKeys(stringValue: "max_supply", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Parsed JSON number <133248297.197> does not fit in Int.", underlyingError: nil))
```

This is indicating that `max_supply` may not be an `Int`, so making that a `Double` might be sufficient: `var maxSupply: Double?`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now everything works fine! May I ask you one more question? totalSupply has Int and Double values. I decoded it with enum QuantumValue. Is it a good practice?

Comment: Without knowing what the implementation of `QuantumValue` is, it's a little hard to answer that question. But overall, if you have multiple potential data types for the same key, an enum is a good solution.