# Can't send json data through Notifications

Tags: swift, notifications

I have **NetworkManager** class in which I make a request to fetch json data and pass them to TableViewController through Notification but the array comes as empty. What can be wrong or should I try another approach to pass data, not Notifications?

```
func loadData() {

guard let url = URL(string: "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest") else {
    
    print("Wrong URL.")
    return
}

let finalURL = url
    var request = URLRequest(url: finalURL)
    request.addValue("my api key", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY")
    
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, responce, error) in
        
        if let jsonData = data {
            
            do {
                
                let cryptoData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .getQuotes, object: cryptoData)
                    
                }                }
            
            catch {
                
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
}
```

**TableViewController**

```
var quotesArray = [CryptoData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    cryptodata.loadData()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(getQuotesData(notification:)), name: .getQuotes, object: nil)
    
    
}

@objc func getQuotesData(notification: Notification) {
    
    if let receivedQuotes = notification.object as? [CryptoData] {
        
        self.quotesArray = receivedQuotes
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably cast your notification object to `Response` type and not `[CryptoData]` in your `getQuotesData(notification:)` function:

```
@objc func getQuotesData(notification: Notification) {
    if let response = notification.object as? Response {
        self.quotesArray = response.data
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed to [Response] type but array is still empty. Here's my struct https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63793345/cant-get-json-data-properly I can print json data but can't send them to TableVC. Did I send the data in right way?

Comment: @Abrcd18 please, follow my answer. Do not type cast object to `[Response]` but to `Response` type. There is major difference.

Comment: Could you please say how to cast the array properly? 

      if let response = notification.object as? Response {
            
            if let receivedQuotes = response.data as? [CryptoData] {
                
                self.quotesArray = receivedQuotes
                
            }
            
        }

Comment: @Abrcd18 cast it like `if let response = notification.object as? Response` and then you can have access to the properties of the `Response` type, which include you array, apparently. `self.quotesArray = response.data`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Error is gone but quoteArray still has no values :(

Comment: @Abrcd18 so, perhaps the decoding of your JSON response is not correct. Try printing `cryptoData.data` variable before you post the notification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221625/discussion-between-gcharita-and-abrcd18).